# Assertion Error vs Assert in pytest, why do I get different error messages when running pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have following dummy test cases in python and I am trying to have a better understanding of the error messages produced by pytest.

when I run these 4 test cases I get the following errors

```
FAILED test_assert_false_2 - AssertionError: assert 'abc' in 'defab'

FAILED test_1 - assert 0

FAILED test_2 - assert 3 < 2

FAILED test_3 - assert 1 > 2
```

why do I get AssertionError in first case and just assert in following cases

```
def test_assert_false_2():
    assert 'abc' in 'defab'

def test_1():
    assert 1
    assert 0

def test_2():
    assert 3 < 2

def test_3():
    a = 2
    b = 1
    assert b > a
```

Comment: I can't find a clear answer in the documentation for pytest, but my best guess it that it may specifically be showing the AssertionError exception directly in the last case because of the use of `in`, as it doesn't use it for `<`, `>` or `==`, even when calling a function.  However, if you look at the long results before the short test summary info, it does indicate that each failed because of an AssertionError on the expected lines.

Answer (score 1):

Pytest tries to provide more debugging information on failed asserts, it does that by rewriting assert statements before they are run and putting introspection information into the assertion failure message. Thus the discrepancy between log messages on different asserts.

You can turn that off by adding --asserts plain to your pytest command

```
pytest --asserts plain
```

More info from pytest --help

```
  --assert=MODE         Control assertion debugging tools.
                        'plain' performs no assertion debugging.
                        'rewrite' (the default) rewrites assert statements in test modules on import to provide assert expression information.
```

You can also disable assert rewriting only for a specific module by adding `PYTEST_DONT_REWRITE` to its docstring

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html#assertion-introspection-details